# How trigger swipeRefreshLayout indicator when activity started or created

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I try to trigger swipeRefreshLayout indicator when my app run but it's not triggered! I have listView with my custom Adapter, I load JSON from an URL and set it in my listView, I want to show loading indicator at first run.
I try these ways:
1.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
   swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
   swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);
   //it's not working!
   swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
   return rootView;
}
```

2.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   // It's not working!!
   swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
}
```

Note: I'm sure my SwipeRefreshLayout is fine because on onStart or onRefresh method worked currently.

Any solution appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with a `Runnable` Method in your `onCreateView`

```
swipeContainer.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks @MounirElfassi